# Joining two dataframes in spark to return only one match

Tags: scala, join, apache-spark, dataframe

I have two dataframes like this:

**DF1:**

```
id  |  name
---
1   |   abc

2   |   xyz
```

**DF2:**

```
id  |  course
---
1   |  c1

1   |  c2

1   |  c3

2   |  c1

2   |  c3
```

When I do a left_outer or inner join of df1 and df2, I want the resultant dataframe to come as:

```
id  | name |  course
--- 
1   | abc  | c1
---
2   | xyz  | c1
---
```

It doesn't matter whether it is c1,c2 or c3 for id 1 when I join; but I need only one record.

Please let me know how can I achieve this in spark.

Thanks,
John

Comment: Actually I have so many columns in my df1. So if I have to group to achieve this, do I have to mention all the columns in my df1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about dropping all duplicated records based on column `id` which will keep only one record for each unique `id` and then join it with `df1`:

```
df1.join(df2.dropDuplicates(Seq("id")), Seq("id"), "inner").show

+---+----+------+
| id|name|course|
+---+----+------+
|  1| abc|    c1|
|  2| xyz|    c1|
+---+----+------+
```

Comment: Yes, Exactly..! This is what I was looking for. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Psidom- however this solves the problem asked by OP, this incurrs extra cost for the query, especially if the join results is in billion/trillions. is there any other cost /time optimized way?